# Programmatically created h:commandButton does not invoke onclick="processInput(id)"

Tags: jsf

Here is how I programmatically create a `<h:commandButton>`:

```
private HtmlCommandButton generateButton(String id,String label){
  HtmlCommandButton button = (HtmlCommandButton)app.createComponent
      (HtmlCommandButton.COMPONENT_TYPE);
  button.setId(id);
  button.setValue(label);
  button.setOnclick("processInput(id)");
  return button;
}
```

When the button is clicked, I need to execute the `processInput(id)` function. However, when I click that button, nothing happens.

Comment: @freak the problem is when i click the button nothing happen

Comment: So please write this statement in your question so others can could understand the queestion clearly.

Comment: Do you see any errors in JavaScript console? What is `id` parameter in your JavaScript function?

Comment: Is `processInput()` a JavaScript function (as your question indicates), or a Java backing bean method (as the actual problem suggests to be; in other words, you're confusing/mixing JavaScript with Java)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onclick function will add the processInput as a JavaScript function . You need to pass the id in your Java method like,

```
setOnClick("processInput(" + id + ")");
```

To add an action method you need to use `setActionExpression`,

```
HtmlCommandButton button = new HtmlCommandButton();
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ELContext ctx = fc.getELContext();
String expression = "#{processInput('id')}";
Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[1];
parameterTypes[0]=String.class;
MethodExpression me = fc.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().
                      createMethodExpression(ctx, 
                      expression, returnType, parameterTypes);
button.setActionExpression(me);
button.setOnclick("alert('');");
```